# Different background colors in each cell R

Tags: r, dataframe, dt, formattable

I have a table look like this:

```
dt <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"),
                 color = c("#D2B48C","#D3D3D3","#CD853F"))
```

How could I show each background color at column `dt$color`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `show_col` function of `scales` package

```
DF <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"),
             color = c("#D2B48C","#D3D3D3","#CD853F"))

library(scales)              
scales::show_col(DF$color)
```

[image]